# Trouble getting a start on this question from the textbook used in college?

Tags: probability, expected-value

> A traveller is lost and at a point where three roads meet. One of the roads will
>   bring her back to the same point after 1 hr of walking, another road will bring
>   her back to the same point after 2 hrs of walking, and the third road will lead her
>   home after 3 hrs of walking. Suppose the traveller uses the following strategy:
>   she picks a road uniformly at random from all the roads she hasn’t yet tried. So,
>   initially she picks one of the three roads with probability 1/3
>   , and if that road leads
>   back to the original point, she picks one of the remaining ones with probability
>   1/2
>   each. What is the expected time it will take her to get home?

I was wondering what the best way would be to start off this question, as that is what I am mainly struggling with as I am quite new to the Expected Value Concepts.

Comment: Just enumerate the paths home.  There are not very many!

Comment: Since you have a small number of possible options, just try and "count." For example, start with her picking the correct path straight away and how long that will take her. Then try to figure out the possible combinations that eventually lead to the right path (e.g. the one hour road then the correct one, or the two hour then the correct one, etc.). With each of these you will get a time amount. After you figure out all of the possible combinations, you can figure out their probabilities. Expectation is just the sum of the probs times the values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Expected value is every outcome multiplied by how likely it is all added together.  All the outcomes are this:

Go straight home (3 hr)

Try the 1 Hr path and then go home (4 hr)

Try the 2 Hr path and then go home (5 hr)

Try both paths before going home (6 hr)

The hardest part is deciding how likely each is.  There aren't many possibilities, so a branching diagram is helpful.  Three branches at first (each 1/3 chance) and from two of those branches another two branches (each with a local 1/2 chance).  Multiply the total branch probabilities for a final probability. The first single branch has a 1/3 chance and all other double-branches have a 1/6 chance.  Multiply by the hours:

3*1/3 + 4*1/6 + 5*1/6 + 6*(1/6+1/6) (The 6hr possibility happens on two of the branches)
I get 4.5 hours like this.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually got the gist a bit better from the comments on the question, but this is well explained with some steps. Really appreciate the help.